# Screenshots using Selenium-RC with JUnit, Java & Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, selenium-rc, webpage-screenshot

I need to take screenshots in Selenium-RC (JUnit, Eclipse & Java). I want to take screenshots anywhere I want and not just on test failure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's your question?  What's wrong with "Prt-Scn"?  What platform are you on?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
selenium.captureScreenshot("/tmp/" + this.getClass().getName() + "."
+ testMethodName + ".png");
```

OR

```
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenShotToString();
```

OR

```
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("C:\screenshot.png","");
```